# Excel bar graph with error bar

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2019

At this point I feel kind of stupid for asking, because I should probably be able to do this.
I want to create a graph like seen on the first image below, with each task having its own label on the x-axis and the error bars being individually adjustable.

I am currently using Excel 2019, but I am open to using something else at this point in time.

[image: Desired Outcome]

So far I have only been able to recreate graphs like the ones below.
The problem with them is that on first it looks like what I want, but the error bars all use the same numbers. This means that I am not able to show the different confidence intervals for the tasks.

[image: First Try]

On the second graph I am able to individually adjust the error bars, but they all the columns have been grouped together under the same label.

[image: Second Try]

I hope that some knows how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quit trying to figure out this problem and switched to Matlab instead, which works perfectly.